# Access violation after stripping ends of a c string

Tags: c++

I get an access violation after stripping the ends of a c string:
"Access violation reading location 0x00000000"

```
void stripEnds(char *src, char *dest)
{
    int i, j;
    free(dest);
    j = strlen(src) - 1;
    if (j <= 0)
        dest = (char*)malloc(1);
    else
        dest = (char*)malloc(j);
    i = 0;
    while (i < j - 1)
    {
        dest[i] = src[i + 1];
        i++;
    }
    dest[i] = 0;
}
```

... in main:

```
char *t = 0;
stripEnds("test", t);
std::cout << t << std::endl; // <- error here
```

I also get an error if I use printf instead of cout.

Comment: Where is your error checking? Why are you using `malloc` in C++? Why are you binding a string literal to a `char*` rather than a `const char*` (or `std::string`)? Strange things here.

Comment: Please do not tag questions C when you are using C++.

Comment: Also `t` is passed by value, and the result of `malloc()` will be gone in `main()`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, ouah already said that in his _answer_!

Comment: Unfortunately in this situation I was having to use a mixture of C and C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some code that does what I was trying to do:

```
str = (char*)calloc(strlen(txt) - 1, sizeof(char));
strncpy(str, &txt[1], strlen(txt) - 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char *t = 0;
stripEnds("test", t);
std::cout << t << std::endl; // <- error here
```

By default C++ is pass-by-value so after your call to `stripEnds` the `t` object is not modified by the function and the `t` object still has its initial value of `0`. To modify `t` you need your function `stripEnds` to have a reference parameter or a pointer to a pointer parameter (here `char **`).

Comment: Better pass by reference.

Comment: or return the allocated stripped string from the function and assign it to `t`?